# TeamCity trigger configuration issue

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have problem with TeamCity trigger.
My VCS configuration that is used in my job:

```
+:refs/heads/(*)
+:refs/pull/(*)/head
```

It means "please inform me on changes made on all branches including master and pull requests".

I configured my job to skip `master` and `RELEASE_CANDIDATE` banches and build only feature and pull request branches so my trigger configuration looks like:

```
+:*
-:master
-:RELEASE_CANDIDATE*
```

But this job that should skip master still is triggered when sb do push to master.
Am I doing sth wrong there?
I went through
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-TriggerRulesExample but I don't see any mistakes in my configuration.
I will apprieciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this on TeamCity official support.
They respondend.

> Hi Rafal, Thank you for the report. It seems that branch filter in VCS
>   trigger does not filter out default branch by name. I created the
>   issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42163, please watch/vote
>   for it. Also did you specify the default branch?
>
> There must be a
>   default branch - it's the branch that build would be triggered against
>   when you press Run button. If the branch is not specified than
>   "refs/heads/master" is set as default branch. So please specify
>   default branch: refs/heads/master and configure the following branch
>   filter in trigger:
>
> `+:*`
>   -:`<default>` 
>   `-:RELEASE*` or leave trigger as is and use any of the feature branches as default. Sorry for the inconvenience.

So if you want this feature please vote for it :) I hope it will help sb.